# How to get column metadata from a table synonym

Tags: sql, sql-server, synonym

How can I determine column metadata from a table [synonym](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191230.aspx) in a SQL Server 2005 database?  I have a synonym called 'ProjectSyn' for a table called 'Project', but I can find no column metadata for the synonym.

My guess is to somewhere determine the 'base table' for the synonym, then query for column metadata for that table.  Is this a correct approach, and if not, what would be?

Comment: @Aliostad - An alternate name for a database object. Useful for renaming objects without breaking legacy code (at least in theory - Sometimes the abstraction doesn't work as in this question). Syntax: `CREATE SYNONYM ProjectSyn FOR Project`

Comment: @Aliostad, I have added a link on the term synonym for an MSDN introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (edited)

```
select c.*
from
   sys.columns c
   inner join sys.synonyms s on c.object_id = object_id(s.base_object_name)
where
   s.name = 'ProjectSyn'
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas, but your code needs a little work.  The OBJECT_NAME function gives an unqualified name, where base_object_name is fully qualified.

Comment: Of course, this will return nothing if the synonym is for an object in a different database on the same server, or even an object on a linked server. Also note that if the synonym was created with brackets as in `[ProjectSyn]` then the base_object_name column will need to have those included as well.

Comment: @ErikE The answer by apc works across databases and even linked servers without needing to match brackets.

Comment: @Arkaine55 I don't understand why you're telling me about a different answer than the one I commented on. Your words are a complete non sequitur. If you want to comment on the other answer that it works across databases & linked servers, go ahead. However, I will say that the only way to work across the linked server is to query the linked server. A query against a local `object_id` is NOT going to work against a linked server.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution which works with synonyms of different databases:

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #TEMP1 FROM YourTable 
SELECT
    [column_name] = c.name,
    [data_type] = t.name,
    [character_maximum_length] = c.max_length
FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
inner join tempdb.sys.types t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE [object_id] = object_id('tempdb..#TEMP1');
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
```

Comment: What about column meta data? That is not included in this answer.

Comment: tempdb.sys.columns c or tempdb.sys.types t contain the meta data fields you will need for example t.name will provide the type name. Try the script with SELECT * to see the availiable fields.

Comment: this is simple and give us something to build on.   Would be clearer if the 1st line read: SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #TEMP1 FROM *YourSynonym*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think getting the base object and then retrieve the columns, is your only option.

To get the base object name for a synonym, just query the view `sys.synonyms`